# How to create an empty std::map object?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I tried this:

```
std::map<int,int> m;
```

and it works -- `m` becomes an empty map. But this approach may not work if the compiler choose to not initialize `m` to an empty map by default.  Better solution?

Comment: This will always make an empty map.  That's what map's default constructor does.

Comment: if your compiler does not emit code that calls the constructor for `m` then your compiler is broken beyond repair

Comment: You're using the default constructor, so you fall under case "1)" here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

Comment: If the compiler didn't initialize `m` to an empty map, what would it put in it?

Comment: I suspect the reason for so many down votes is that you could have found this out very easily yourself. I suggest referring to cppreference when you have such questions, and you'll see that most answers can be found there :)

Comment: What makes you think the compiler is going to randomly "choose" how to initialize the map?

Comment: @Eric Good question. In C, "int x" may produce different values for x depending on whether x is local, global, and on the compilers , right? But this does not seem to be an obvious question after all, e.g. asking default values of local variables was a question in Java Interview.

Comment: @zell you are talking about unitialized variables which is undefined behaviour. Objects however are always going to be initialized based on their constructor once you instanciate them. If you dont provide one the compiler will generate the default one for you.

Comment: @Eric I see! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Any better solution?

Taking your question literally, no. There is no better solution.

This will create [a default constructed, and therefore empty](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) `std::map<int,int>`.

```
std::map<int,int> m;
```